# Reviewing suggested edits that only add code language

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, code-formatting

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3599495) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3587796) are a few of a series of similar suggested edits by the same sub-2000 rep user that do nothing but add

```
<!-- language: lang-dart -->
```

in front of code blocks.

The top answer for ["How do I format my code blocks"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks/22189#22189) states this:

> Prettify is used to add colour to the code, but only if the language can be uniquely determined given the tags of the question, or if manual hints have been provided in HTML comments

Which seems to indicate that with properly tagged questions (like these ones), adding this language specific formatting hint on the cod blocks should be completely unnecessary. I can't see any difference in the before-after on them, though I admit I'm not familiar with this particular language.

In general, it's not clear to me whether this type of edit should be approved (as what seems to be happening) or not.  **What should be happening here?**

Comment: For me they are too minor. On the other hand, if they are **needed** for proper highlight, they should be treated like retags (accepted or improved-accepted even if nothing else is added).

Comment: Thats the thing - I dont think they were necessary at all, since the proper tags already existed

Comment: I just asked a similar question and immediately got an [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375793/1139806) that also answers this question. Linking for the sake of findability.